# 0% coverage error on running specified tests while validating/deploying any change set in Production

Tags: unit-test, deployment, code-coverage, failing-tests

I am getting `0% code coverage error` while trying to validate changesets in production using `run specified tests`. I tried 3 unrelated deployments and all of them gave the same error. The changesets are getting validated if I don't select the `run specified tests` option. I am providing each test class on a new line in the `run specified tests` option. The error says that all the test classes have 0% coverage. The classes do have coverage in sandbox.

As the deployments are unrelated, the problem does not seem to be in test classes. Also the changeset validates if I don't use `run specified tests`.

No new validation rules or process builders are added to production. I am not sure what the problem is. Please guide. Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried by using the commas instead of adding the each test class in separate line which should fix the issue.Ex:Test1,Test2,Test3,....etc

Comment: @ShirishaPathuri Thank You for the response! No, I have not tried that. I always do deployments by pasting test classes on a new line so there is no reason it should not work this time. Anyways, I'll try it.

Comment: @ShirishaPathuri You were right! That was the problem. Thank You! I am not sure why I never got this problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,test classes separated by commas should work.You can see the information on using Comma in [this](https://www.salesforcetutorial.com/running-specified-tests-changeset-deployment/) for multiple test classes.